# What is the correct usage of PyArray_SIZE?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm new to manipulating numpy arrays in C. Here is a snippet of code that lets me 1) pass a list of 1-D, 64-bit-float numpy arrays to C and 2) loop through each array, printing its contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include "list_of_ndarrays_lib.h"

void print_all(PyObject *list) {

    int i, j;
    PyArrayObject *arrayObj;
    double *arrayData;

    for (i = 0; i < PyObject_Length(list); i++) {

        arrayObj = (PyArrayObject *) PyList_GET_ITEM(list, i);

        arrayData = PyArray_DATA(arrayObj);
        for (j = 0; j < PyArray_SHAPE(arrayObj)[0]; j++) {
            printf("%f ", arrayData[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

This code works, but `PyArray_SHAPE(arrayObj)[0]` doesn't generalize to n-dimensional arrays, and if I replace it with `PyArray_SIZE(arrayObj)`, I get a segmentation fault.

What am I doing wrong with `PyArray_SIZE`?

Comment: So are you trying to print all the elements of a flattened `arrayData`?  Or should the n-dimensional shape affect the printing layout?

Comment: Yes, just printing all elements of the flattened version. (I'm just using print as a general operation that iterates over all elements because it's the simplest example that illustrates the problem.)

Comment: The size of a numpy array is the product of the element of the shape... you could compute this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here might be that all of the Py* functionality, including the PyArray* functionality, is at-your-own-risk *unless* you properly modify your code to become a C extension module.

A clear writeup on the subject is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209013811/http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/). There is a little bit of boilerplate, but other than that, this method is pretty nice. No external dependencies (like Boost.Python), and it makes your Python code very clean, eliminating the need for specifying function signatures via ctypes.

Comment: That link is now spam.

https://web.archive.org/web/20151209013811/http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/

Comment: I just verified and replaced it with its archived version

Answer (score 2):

Just add `import_array();` call in the print_all() beginning. It will initialize the array functions C-API.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some `cython` coding, but not the more basic `c` work.  But since no one else has answered I'll throw out a few thoughts.

A possibly relevant doc section is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#getting-at-ndarray-memory-and-accessing-elements-of-the-ndarray.

Another tool for iterating on an array is `nditer`. I'm familiar with its use in `python` and `cython`. There's a good intro page.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html

Another thing to do is look a `numpy` source code.  I'd go to the github repository, and do a search on this variable.

Your iteration with SHAPE is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    print arr[i]
```

Your `arrayData[j]` is using the same array indexing code as the Python version.

The 2d equivalent (in Python) is:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        print arr[i,j]
```

I suspect the c equivalent has a similar structure.

```
for i in range (arr.size):
     print arr[i]
```

gets a `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`.  I assume without bounds checking you get a segmentation fault instead.

I suspect with `SIZE` you need to through the `DATA` bufer directly, rather than working with some form of `arrayData[j]`.  In other words, get the buffer pointer, and step that by `itemsize` `SIZE` number of times.

`nditer` will save you a lot of that detailed work.

---

A several places in numpy/core calculations.c  I see a block like:

```
n = PyArray_SIZE(ap)/m;
rptr = (npy_intp *)PyArray_DATA(rp);
for (ip = PyArray_DATA(ap), i = 0; i < n; i++, ip += elsize*m) {
    arg_func(ip, m, rptr, ap);
    rptr += 1;
}
```

If `m=1`, this should step the `ip` pointer through the data buffer, element by element (each `elsize` bytes long), passing it to `arg_func` for action.  More often `PyArray_SIZE` is used to check whether the array is empty (==0).

---

Another option is to use `PyArray_Flatten` (or better `PyArray_Ravel`) to flatten the array, and then uses the `SHAPE` iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looking through the numpy C source is a good idea; will do. Small note: I'm worried about using their iterator because it seems to be general to any object, whereas looping through a contiguous array has none of the associated overhead. This could just be bad intuition on my part though. Maybe they wrote the iterator in a clever way.

Comment: I'm a little surprised how few examples I found of using SIZE in iteration.  Treating the data buffer as a C array is fast, but limited.  The (nd)iterator gives you access to the array elements as numpy objects, without further indexing overhead.  It is also great if you are iterating over multiple arrays in a coordinated fashion (e.g. z[i]=x[i]*y[i]).